# C stack allocation size

Tags: c, memory, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to answer a quiz regarding the following code:

```
struct B {
  int _arr[5];
};
struct A{
  struct B* _b;
};

#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   struct A arr[5];
   struct A * a = (struct A*)malloc(sizeof (struct A));
   return 0;
}
```

I am trying to understand how much memory (in bytes) is allocated on the program's stack.

So I first used the following (and probably wrong) logic:

1. Calculated size of struct B =  sizeof(int) * 5 = 20;
2. Calculated size of struct A = sizeof(B) = 20

I know that `2` is actualy wrong, because when I printed sizeof(B) I got a surprising 8. I really don't understandy why.

Anyway, to understand how much memory was allocated on the stack:

1. The size of `arr` according to my logic is 20 * 5 = 100;
2. About *a, I don't really know. printing `sizeof(a)` shows 8, but again I don't understand why.
3. The sum of that is 108

BUT the actual answer is 24 :/ 
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The "actual answer" is "can't tell".

Comment: Calculated size of struct A = sizeof(B) = 20... should be: `Calculated size of struct A = sizeof(*B) = sizeof(pointer for the arch)`

Comment: It's unlikely `sizeof(struct A) == sizeof(struct B)`. You are missing the crucial part of this exercise, pointers vs. pointees.

Comment: The question has no definitive answer. For example, what made you think that `sizeof(int)` is 4? C language does specify how large `int` is.

Comment: assuming pointers are 4 bytes: `struct A arr[5];` = 20 and `struct A * a` is 4... and the malloc doesn't happen on the stack

Comment: The C standard does not say that there must be stack. However, I'd suspect that the number of *bytes allocated on the program's stack* is always non-negative, and usually integer... :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's *usually* non-negative. You can never tell what some runtime environments are going to do.

Comment: @tadman the address could be negative, and it could grow either direction, but the magnitude couldn't be negative in any meaningful way

Comment: @tadman I mean, I cannot see how one could allocate a negative number of bytes, but yeah, it might be possible :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's like a hole you've got to dig yourself out of. C has been around for a long, long time, and it's had to target some pretty sketchy hardware.

Comment: So what is actually going on here? How can it still be 24?

Comment: @superuser123 I compiled with `gcc -O3` and the answer is that 0 bytes are allocated. The code for `main` in assembler is `xorl    %eax, %eax; ret`

Comment: @tadman array of five int? it's an array of struct, how can it be the same?

Comment: @tadman, antti: `sizeof` yields a `size_t` which is an **unsigned** integer, hence it cannot be negative. Addresses otoh are neither positive nor negative.They are not integers. Conversion of an address to an integer is implementation dependent.

Comment: @tadman: Plus there is no stack in C (which antti already stated above). Consider the implications.

Comment: @tad: did you even read my last comment or antti's? If you did, you did not understand the implications of the comments. I also did not say anything related.

Comment: @tadman: I give up. What about "there is no stack in C" is unclear and how do you conclude I wote it would be squirrels? Nevertheless, `sizeof` is well defined. Not only for the type it returns, but also the unit. But feel free to provide the section in the standard specifying squirrels. The versions I know are clear about bytes, i.e. `char`.

Comment: @tadman: What does that change about the unit of `sizeof`? If you have an architecture with e.g. 13 bits are smallest single accessible unit, a byte would have 13 bits. It still is a byte. And gcc is not the world, nor are x86 or ARM. They are in fact the vast **minority** of CPUs and gcc only covers few architectures (and some smaller ones not really good). And, well, "there is no stack in C" **is** correct. I did not say anything about a specific implementation.

Comment: @tadman: I shouldn't have continued the discussion after my first good-bye. You seem not to get the point and confuse two or three things. Please read the standard carefully, namely the discussed parts. I'll definitively leave it here; feel free to follow my advice or just go on. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Olaf I've pulled all my comments from here because we're obviously not on the same page and this is counter-productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there isn't really a correct answer. It's a terrible question, and in order to answer it you have to assume things which are not defined by C.

That's probably not very helpful, though. Since you know the "correct" answer, it's possbile to figure out how they arrived at it:

If you assume 32-bit pointers, `sizeof(struct A) == 4` since `struct A`'s only field is a pointer to a `struct B`. So `arr` is `4 * 5 = 20` bytes, then add another 4 bytes for the `a` variable (which is another pointer).

All the talk of `sizeof(int)` in the comments above is pointless; there are no `int`s on the stack. Or the heap, for that matter; you never actually allocate any `struct B`s.

Comment: To repeat the most important fact: **there are neither heap nor stack in the C language. It is not even mandatory `malloc` is actually called/used by this code or anything allocated at all. See the abtract machine and the "as-if" rule.

Comment: That's true, but I think @superuser123 was just trying to understand why the hell his teacher thought 24 was the "right" answer. Language-lawyering probably isn't helpful for them, and as someone who noticed a lot of things wrong with the material when I was learning it, I can confirm that correcting the teacher and/or questioning the material generally isn't the best course of action (selfishly speaking; obviously it would be nice to get it fixed for future students).